# Getting errors with std::copy in visual express 2010

Tags: c++

I'm getting errors: 
C2036: 'void *' : unknown size
C2100: illegal indirection
C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'CUSTOMVERTEX' to 'void *'

```
 VOID* pVertices;
if( FAILED( g_pVB->Lock( 0, sizeof( Vertices ), ( void** )&pVertices, 0 ) ) )
    return E_FAIL;
std::copy( Vertices, Vertices, pVertices );
g_pVB->Unlock();

return S_OK;
```

not sure whats wrong

Comment: vertices is an array and CUSTOMVERTEX is a struct

Comment: @user3606: That comment is unclear.  Is `Vertices` a _class_ or is it a _variable_?  If it's a variable, what is it's type?

Answer (score 3):

for [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) you need three iterators as argument. In your invocation the undicsolsed Vertices might be suitable, though it would be an empty range so you can just cut the copy.

The last one must be an output iterator, compatible with the input. void* is definitely wrong, as you can't increment it, or dereference it for assignment purpose.